how to identify unused usb ports in linux
I have been searching across the internet about a way to get a list of unused usb ports so that i can check whether those unused ports are disabled or not, but there's no such info.
does anyone have an approach or a solution for this?

I'm not sure it's possible. lsusb lists among all essentially "virtual" USB ports that have no physical sockets on your PC/laptop.
